# How to read a complex text file using spring batch having multiple formats

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-batch, filereader, reader

I have a text file which is having multiple format in it.....how do i read it using spring batch reader?

Example: file

```
DATE: 09/12/2018.           SERIAL NO: 12345
BANK: HDFC                  IFSC NO: 9876


                    NAME           NO. OF FD.          AMOUNT
                    ABC.                   5            100                  
                    XYZ.                   7            200
                    DEF.                   7            200
                    JKL.                  10            300
TOTAL.                                    29            800

REJECTED REQUEST:                  1 
BRANCH NAME:                  Atlanta
```

Every sample I am getting online is with tokenizers.......how do I read it in this case where it could be multiple records and formats

note*** the values will be of fixed length/range

Object I am hoping to make for the complete report:

```
 private String date;        
 private String Serial; 
 private String bank;        
 private String ifsc;
 private List<RowData> rows;
 private string totalFD;
 private String totalAmount;
 private String rejectedRequest;
 private String branchName
```

Row Data Object (The rows or record which would be variable) mentioned above would be as below:

```
 private String name;        
 private String noOfFD; 
 private String amount;
```

Comment: What is the type of item in your case?. You said: "the values will be of fixed length/range" . Have you tried to use the `FixedLengthTokenizer`?

Comment: PatternMatchingCompositeLineMapper<Product> mapper = new PatternMatchingCompositeLineMapper<>();

  Map<String, LineTokenizer> tokenizers = new HashMap<String, LineTokenizer>();
  tokenizers.put("DATE*", mobilePhoneProductLineTokenizer());
  tokenizers.put("NAME*", bookProductLineTokenizer());
  mapper.setTokenizers(tokenizers);

  Map<String, FieldSetMapper<Product>> mappers = new HashMap<String, FieldSetMapper<Product>>();
  mappers.put("DATE*", mobilePhoneProductFieldSetMapper());
  mappers.put("NAME*", bookProductFieldSetMapper());
  mapper.setFieldSetMappers(mappers);

Comment: I have used something like above...Multiple tokenizer and multiple FieldsetMapper.......what "FieldSetMapper" is doing is....its creating different object for every field setMapper.....

I want all the value tokenized to be put into a single object for each file......

How to achieve that?????

Comment: @MahmoudBenHassine Can you please help on this????? Please let me know if more explanation is required?

Comment: Please don't add code in comments, you can always edit the question and add code there. `I want all the value tokenized to be put into a single object for each file` I don't see how this is possible. With the `PatternMatchingCompositeLineMapper`, you will have a different object type for each **line** (not file) according to the matching pattern of that line. You can find an example here: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/blob/master/spring-batch-infrastructure/src/test/java/org/springframework/batch/item/file/mapping/PatternMatchingCompositeLineMapperTests.java#L37

Comment: @MahmoudBenHassine I have edited the question above. Please see the explanation.....I hope that my motive would be clear to you now.

Basically only 1 Object for the Complete Report

Answer (score 0):

> The rows or record which would be variable

Since the number of data records is variable, you can use the `SingleItemPeekableItemReader` to peek an item ahead and see if it is of type `RowData` or a header/footer type.

You can find two samples similar to your use case here:

- [Multiline Job](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/tree/master/spring-batch-samples#multiline)
- [Multiline Order Job](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/tree/master/spring-batch-samples#multiline-order-job)